# Why object's destructor was called after assignment operation is done

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, destructor

I have written this class and driver function:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Weight {
    int grams;
    int kilograms;

public:

    Weight(int kg, int g) : kilograms(kg), grams(g) {
    }

    ~Weight() {
        cout << "Destructor " << this->kilograms << " " << this->grams << "\n";
    }

    friend Weight operator+(const Weight& a, const Weight& b);

    Weight operator+(const Weight& w) const {
        cout << "member operator+\n";
        int newKg = this->kilograms + w.kilograms;
        int newG = this->grams + w.grams;
        if (newG >= 1000) {
            newG -= 1000;
            newKg += 1;
        }
        return Weight(newKg, newG);
    }

    Weight operator+(const int addition) const {
        cout << "operator+int" << endl;
        int newKg = this->kilograms;
        int newG = this->grams + addition;
        if (newG >= 1000) {
            newG -= 1000;
            newKg += 1;
        }
        return Weight(newKg, newG);
    }

    Weight operator+(const double addition) const {
        cout << "operator+double" << endl;
        int newKg = this->kilograms + ((int) addition);
        int newG = this->grams + (1000 * (addition - ((int) addition)));
        if (newG >= 1000) {
            newG -= 1000;
            newKg += 1;
        }
        return Weight(newKg, newG);
    }

    Weight& operator=(const Weight & w) {
        cout << "Assignment operator\n";
        this->grams = w.grams;
        this->kilograms = w.kilograms;
        return *this;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "Weight is: " << this->kilograms << " Kilograms and " << this->grams <<
                " Grams\n";
    }

};

Weight operator+(const Weight& a, const Weight& b) {

    cout << "Friend plus\n";
    int newKg = a.kilograms + b.kilograms;
    int newG = a.grams + b.grams;
    if (newG >= 1000) {
        newG -= 1000;
        newKg += 1;
    }
    return Weight(newKg, newG);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Weight m(90, 900);
    m = m + 1.1;
    m = m + m;
    m.print();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
operator+double
Assignment operator
Destructor 92 0
Friend plus
Assignment operator
Destructor 184 0
Weight is: 184 Kilograms and 0 Grams
Destructor 184 0
```

Why the destructor was called twice after the two assignment operators were called? (i.e., third and sixth lines in the output).

I know these are probably for the temporary variable being used for the addition, but what is the rule or C++ specification for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because indeed the `operator+` creates a temporary object which is the result of the operation, and is discarded after the assignment.

Consider your own signature for the `operator+`: `Weight operator+(const double addition) const`. This returns, by value, a `Weight` object instance. This isn't a reference, nor a pointer. It's a de-facto new object that is created to hold the result of `m + 1.1`, without updating the value of `m` first (unlike `operator+=`). This is even more evident from a look in your own code: `return Weight(newKg, newG);` - a new object is created right here, and it needs to be destroyed.

This temporary value is then assigned into `m`, and the temporary object is then destroyed as it moves out of scope.

As a side note, what you see here is also an optimization (a standard optimization called "return value optimization") as the explicit behavior for this situation would've been the construction of the temporary value in the `return` statement inside the stack frame of the `operator+`, followed by a copy-construction of the value in the stack frame of the calling function `main` and then the destruction of the object in the `operator+` stack frame. Then the value in `main` would've gone into the assignment operator, and then destroyed too. Your compiler just optimized this code to construct the return value directly on the stack frame of the calling function saving an extra temporary object.

Comment: So, where are these returned values stored? how they survive the end of function call? what determines their scope?

Comment: @hebbo To which objects do you refer?
The objects created on the stack frame? The stack frame still exists while the new objects are created and copied outside, The stack exists all the way until the stack frame (ebp) register is popped from the stack and the return (ret) instruction pops the program counter and stack pointer (esp) returning to the caller function